# "how long is it since" vs. "how long ago"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Is there a difference in meaning between the following sentences:

> How long is it since you last visited a museum?
> How long ago did you visit a museum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning, not even in nuance.

> How long … since

may be more common in speech and informal writing, and

> How long ago did …

may be more common in formal writing, but I know no way to validate that feeling.